# typed weakreferencequeu in scala

Tags: scala, generics, types, generic-type-argument

Here is example code

```
object Main extends App {

  import java.lang.ref._
  private val rq = new ReferenceQueue[Any]()
  class MyWR1(o: Object) extends WeakReference(o, rq) // this is ok

  private val myrq = new ReferenceQueue[MyWR2]() // Any changed to MyWR
  class MyWR2(o: Object) extends WeakReference(o, myrq) // illegal cyclic reference involving class MyWR2

}
```

which is [said](http://scastie.org/13451) to contain cyclic class references.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am asking for the proper use of the ref queue, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ReferenceQueue wants the parameter of the tracked referent rather than the type of WeakRef pointer that it will produce in the `poll`. In my best attempt, I had to cast the type to my WeakRef

```
  import java.lang.ref._

  val myrq = new ReferenceQueue[List[Int]]() // Any changed to MyWR
  class MyWR(val name: String, referent: List[Int]) extends WeakReference(referent, myrq) // illegal cyclic reference involving class MyWR2

  val wr1 = new MyWR("ref1", List(1)) // keep this otherwise it won't be reported

  def forceGc(id: Int, sum: Int) {
    val a = Array.fill[Int](1000000)(1)
    myrq.poll match {
        case null => println(id); forceGc(id+1, sum + a.length)
        case top => println ("done " + top.asInstanceOf[MyWR].name + ", ref must be null now and is " + top.get)
    }
  } ; forceGc(0, 0)
```

prints out

```
done ref1, ref must be null now and is null
```

You should keep hard link to the weak ref in order it to be reported obsolete from GC. You should not also make your weak ref a case class and not to use `val` parameter for the referent that you pass to the ReferenceQueue in order not to keep hard references to the referent.